# Understanding hypothetical reasoning and material implication

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-mathematics, philosophy-of-language, semantics

I am a little bit frustrated in how we use hypothetical reasoning in everyday life. Many times we make "if-then" statements. For example, if I get ill ,then I can't go to work and if I can't go to work , then I can't get money. But I have a problem in understanding the antecedent. It says in the case I get ill but does this says anything else about the real world? I mean it isn't sure that I won't get money because maybe a rich man give me tons of dollars. So when we do hypothetical reasoning we take as granted the world, how we live now, and modify some conditions? Also the above example is a material implication or an example of hypothetical reasoning?

Comment: If we use the "classical" (truth-functional) model for the propositional connectives, the key feature of the *conditional* ("if..., then...") is its interaction with *modus ponens*. Asserting the *conditional* : "(if I get ill ,then I can't go to work) and (if I can't go to work , then I can't get money)" **and** assuming the case that I'm ill, we are licensed to use *mp* (twice) to "detach" the consequent, concluding that I will not be paid.

Comment: This mechanism is the basic of math deduction: we have an axiom (or already proved theorem) **A** and we want to prove a new theorem **T**. If we succeed in deducing the statement "**if A, then T**", we can use *mp* and we have a proof of **T** (in the context of the theory with axiom **A**).

Comment: I'd say the statement "if I can't go to work, then I can't get money" is false, so the issue isn't logic. The correct statement would be (assuming you don't get sick days or whatever): "if I can't go to work, then I can't get money FROM WORK (unless they decide to give me money for some reason other than working); however, I could certainly get money from other sources". A specific example would be: if I get ill, I can't go to work. If I get ill, I can get apply for disability. If I get disability, I get money.

Comment: Yes, practical inferences of everyday reasoning use background assumptions and presuppositions that are never explicitly stated, and can not be made fully explicit *in principle*. Sometimes a catchall phrase [*ceteris paribus* (other things being equal)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceteris_paribus) is used, but often not even that. The conditionals themselves are not only not material, they are not formally valid in any sense.They rely on context specific warrants, see [argumentation theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argumentation_theory#Toulmin_Model_of_Argument).

Answer (score 3):

Real conditionals often, perhaps usually, do not behave like material implications. Because of that, some common rules that apply to material implication do not always work with real conditionals. Such rules include hypothetical syllogism, contraposition and strengthening of the antecedent (monotonocity). Often when we express a conditional we have in mind some background circumstances that hold by default but might have exceptions. For example:

1. If Alice spends lots of money on luxury goods she'll become poor.
2. If Alice wins the lottery she will spend lots of money on luxury goods. 
   But not:
3. If Alice wins the lottery she'll become poor.

This is an example of hypothetical syllogism failing. Another, discussed by Ernest Adams, is

4. If President Brown's party loses the election he will resign after the election.
5. If President Brown dies before the election, his party will lose the election. 
   But not:
6. If President Brown dies before the election, he will resign after the election.

In each case, there is a shift in the assumed default circumstances between the two premises and this suffices to prevent the conclusion being valid. These are similar to your example. By default, it is reasonable to suppose that if you can't work you won't get money, because this is the normal way you get money. But there are obviously exceptions. As you say, someone might give you the money, or you might win a bet on the horses, or a rich uncle might leave you an inheritance. In practice, it is infeasible to list all the circumstances needed to turn a real conditional into a true set of necessary and sufficient conditions, so we don't bother and make do with default assumptions. We then take it as read that that these defaults might turn out false.

Ernest Adams' probability logic copes well with this kind of situation. It may be highly probable that C given B, and highly probable that B given A, but it does not always follow that it is highly probable that C given A.

Comment: "If Alice spends lots of money on luxury goods [then] she'll become poor." This suggests a causal link between between spending and poverty. As such, it is not a material implication. We might convert it to a material implication as follows: "If Alice spends a lot on luxury goods, then she IS poor." In other words, it is not the case that both "Alice spends a lot on luxury goods" is true and "Alice is poor" is false.

Comment: @DanChristensen I think you misunderstood Bumble's answer -- you might want to read the first paragraph again.

Comment: @EliranH Bumble wrote: "Real conditionals OFTEN, PERHAPS USUALLY, do not behave like material implications." (My emphasis) I gave an example of "real conditional" (example 1)  that might be easily converted to a material implication.

Comment: @DanChristensen perhaps it might be converted to a material conditional, but that does not mean that the original was one.

Comment: @EliranH The is no suggestion of causality or changes over time in the material implication. In this case, the material implication describes the state of things at an instant in time. It may even be a more honest portrayal of reality.

Comment: @EliranH To establish causality in science, for example, is not something you can casually infer. It often involves many long and exhaustive studies (e.g. to establish that smoking actually causes cancers required proving the chemical and biological chain of events from breathing in tobacco smoke to the growth of cancerous tumors.).

Comment: If your answer is specific to Mathematical Logic you need to make your response clear that you are not also talking about other types of logic systems.  Your explanation makes no sense in a Philosophy context.  You have made no distinction between what you call REAL or otherwise.  All conditional statements are not necessary or sufficient in the real world use (especially in slang if. . . Then statements are used often).  Your statements 1-3 are no different from other conditional statements which have a context.  Why do mathematicians say there are two propositions when there is only one?

Comment: @DanChristensen I don't disagree with what you say about causation, but I don't think it affects my point. Conditionals may express all kinds of relations, including causation, evidential relations, preconditions, legal consequences, etc. But in any event, all of these 'real world' examples are not material implications because there will always be some unstated "other things being equal" consideration. MIs do not allow for such considerations: they strictly express sufficient conditions. I disagree that you can convert my first example into a MI just by using the present tense 'is'.

Comment: @Logikal I'm not sure I understand your comment. If by 'mathematical logic' you mean logic done using symbols, then there are many kinds of mathematical logic. My examples are of ordinary English conditionals, which is what I mean by 'real'. My point is that while there might be many different ways of systematizing the logic of conditionals like this, they do not behave like MIs.

Comment: You use the term material implication and never distinguish it from slang conditions. From your answer I don't see any difference between the two. Again, you don't go into material implication enough in your answer. There are reasons the name is material implication and not conditional alone. Any literal meaningful proposition in the If . . . Then . . . Form could be both. You need a clear distinction for both or what is the point?

Comment: @Logikal I'm taking it as read that people know what material implication means. It is a truth function with the table T/F/T/T and is logically equivalent to not( A and not B). That serves to distinguish it from other kinds.

Comment: That is only ONE context and not the only truth table for a conditional.  ~p V q is another; ~(p & ~q) is also another.  Why are you focused on one context?

Comment: @Bumble Re: Your first example. By changing the consequent from "Alice will become poor" to "Alice IS poor," you change it to an logical proposition that is unambiguously either true or false at some instant in time -- the stuff of material implication. If someone is going to suggest that personal spending causes poverty, they should be more forthright about it and explicitly state it. Then it becomes an issue for science, not a purely logical or mathematical analysis.

Comment: @DanChristensen Again, I don't disagree with what you say about causation, but your proposal is too revisionary for my liking. In practice, we use conditionals for all kinds of purposes in ordinary language and it is helpful to have some generic way of expressing them. In particular, many conditionals have an assertability condition that it is highly probable that B supposing A. We can use this to derive a logic of conditionals that is independent of the grounds for believing the conditional. Ernest Adams pursued this approach in "The Logic of Conditionals" and "A Primer on Probability Logic".

Comment: @Bumble Re: "It is highly probable that B supposing A." In a single test trial, if you know that A is true, then B may or may not be true. To me, it seems a stretch to call it a conditional or implication statement. I am also not convinced that any conditional other than material implication is required even in natural language. I don't think we need to elevate every misuse of language to something worthy of serious scholarly analysis. These misuses, like mistakes in grammar or spelling, should ideally be eliminated from popular discourse. It seems to me to be problem of pedagogy.

Comment: @DanChristensen Well in that case we are much further apart than I thought. I disagree completely with your last comment. Unfortunately, this isn't the place to discuss it.

Comment: @Bumble So we could include those assumptions in the antecedent right? For example if it is true "If A and B then C" and we know that B is always true then we just need to have A in order to have C. Is this what we do when we don't state that assumptions?

Comment: In practice it is infeasible to list all the possible circumstances or assumptions in the antecedent. To take your example: If I get ill, and nobody will take me to work, and my boss won't allow me to work from home, and I can't find other ways of earning money from home, and I can't get welfare payments, and etc, etc...

Answer (score 2):

In natural language, material implication works only for pairs of logical propositions that are both unambiguously either true or false at some instant in time. Like mathematics as a whole, material implication has nothing to do with causality or the passage of time.

P implies Q means only that it is not the case that both P is true and Q is false. This is often given as definition in textbooks, but it can be derived from other well-accepted principles of logic.

Comment: You refer to a single context of p implies q.  What about the others?  (~p v q), ~(p & ~q),  (p-->(p & q), and so on.  Why did you pick one out of many context which all are identical by truth table.  Are you only addressing Mathematical Logic and not the others?

Comment: @Logikal Since they are all logically equivalent, I picked the one that I thought was easiest to use and understand.

Comment: You do know that the truth table is equivalent but the contexts are different right?  The propositions listed each express something different.  The term equivalent does not mean the same thing a identical.  Do you acknowledge that there are different logic systems and all logic is not mathematics?  Initially only Philosophy used the term Material Implication as in a special context to differentiate the common use of conditionals.  Math has no need to use the term Material Implication as the philosophers once did. So why use it in Mathematical Logic?  The intention is different & it’s purpose.

Comment: @Logikal 1. Each of expressions that you list can be derived from any of the others. So, they are each interchangable. I don't see that context has anything to do with it.  2. I don't rule out the possibility of inventing other forms of logic, but I am not convinced that it is necessary.  3. AFAIK material implication is the only form of conditional used by the vast majority of mathematicians.

Comment: you confuse truth tables with reality.  Because the truth tables match doesn't mean the ideas express the same context.  I take it you are looking at logic as it is only math and math is logic.  I also gather by your response your definition of what a proposition is doesn't match how Philosophy defines proposition.  You should be aware that Mathematical Logic did not exist prior to 1845.  There was no mathematical logic in Aristotle's day or the medieval periods either.  Mathematical Logic is the legit NAME of the topic.  There are multiple text that correctly identify this.

Comment: @Logikal The standard truth table for logical (or material) implication does reflect reality. It can actually be derived using the logical principles of (1) direct proof (introducing =>), (2) proof by contradiction, (3) detachment (MP), and (4) elimination of double negations. I contend that each of these principles is self-evident even in popular discourse or should be -- again, a problem of pedagogy, not with the principles of logic themselves. (See my derivation the truth table of material implication at my blog posting http://www.dcproof.com/IfPigsCanFly.html )

Comment: There are clear examples that all conditionals in reality are not viewed in mathematical logic.  For example, if the NY Jets win the Super Bowl this year, I will run through Times Square, Manhattan naked.  This does not express a mathematical logic statement.  Even if the antecedent is true I can renege on the part of my running around naked portion.  The claim was never to be taken literally.  The claim expresses that I think the NY Jets is not good enough to be Super Bowl champions this year.  What you meant to say is that SOME conditionals can express reality.

Comment: @Logikal Re: "If the NY Jets win the Super Bowl this year, I will run through Times Square, Manhattan naked." The consequent is not unambiguously either true or false. Better would be: "If the NY Jets win the Super Bowl in 2019, I will run through Times Square, Manhattan naked at noon EST the next day at Broadway and 44th Street." Equivalently then, the speaker could say, "It is not the case that the Jets win the the Super Bowl in 2018 and I do NOT run naked through Times Square, etc." A material implication.

Comment: You are missing the point sir.  Even with your revision I am not obligated on my part to do anything.  That is, the anrecedant can in fact be true while the consent is false.  Reality is not Mathematical logic.  Mathematical logic has its place but it is not all places.

Comment: @Logikal In that case, the implication would be false.

Comment: I take it then you think every statement  in a conditional format is a legitimate proposition in Mathematical logic?  You seem to still miss the point of the claim.  My example does not Express truth functionality at all but expresses a rhetorical context. You seem to be stuck k with the form and not what is being expressed. I am pretty sure you and I define the term proposition differently.  I define proposition as typically the old school philosophy way and NOT the way mathematicans define the term proposition. I find it intentionally deceiving not to say you are using Mathematical logic.

Comment: @Logikal I'm not certain, but it seems to me that most if not all conditional statements, whether in mathematics or common discourse -- even in jest -- can be restated as a material implication in a way that preserves the essential meaning, provided the antecedent and consequent are sufficiently precise: It would not be case that both the antecedent is true and the consequent is false. The implication would be false if and only if the both the antecedent is true and the consequent is false.

Comment: Your claim is clearly false if I find at least one interpretation where the antecedent us true and the consequent  is false.  I gave such an example and I further demonstrated that Rhetoric uses conditional statements as well. In Rhetoric every conditional statement is not truth functional.  The statement expresses something outside of truth functionality: it is rooted in emotion.  You are strange if you ask about truth functionality of the following statement: if you are a NY Met fan, then you need a brain transplant.  Asking if that is true shows lack of personal skills or lack of language.

Comment: @Logikal Re: "If you are a NY Met fan, then you need a brain transplant." With your, ahem... superior personal and language skills, please explain why this is NOT logically equivalent to: "It is not the case that you are both a NY Met fan and do not need a brain transplant."

Comment: The statement does not express a logical proposition at all -- that is why.  The statement is pure rhetoric & not intended for people to seriously consider.  In this way what is expressed is NOT "it is not the case that you are both a NY Met fan and do not need a brain transplant."  More than likely math does not teach the concept of what a proposition is correctly in most cases.  Most cases I am familiar with is that thousands of math students are taught propositions are the same things as literal sentences or you will get propositions are literally declarative sentences. They ignore context.

Comment: @Logikal Re: "The statement is pure rhetoric & not intended for people to seriously consider." So, as far as you are concerned, it is nothing but gibberish. It just happens to have the words "if" and "then" embedded in it so you call it a "conditional?" And you give these as examples in a serious philosophical discussion about logic and language??? Can you not give some more meaningful examples? If not, there is really no point in continuing this discussion.

Comment: I gave you examples of other truth functional equivalents but you think all of them express the same context or you think context doesn't matter. I gave the example I gave because you read to literally.  We do not disagree on meaningful propositions.  Your approach seems overly robotic.  You may think everything can be made mathematical which you seem to EXPRESS heavily and I showed you a case where you can use the if . . . then pattern and not mean what you think it literally means. You seem to express that you will ignore that part anyway.  Do you teach students about conditionals like that?

Comment: @Logikal Re: "We do not disagree on meaningful propositions." So, we do not disagree on anything significant -- a tempest in a teacup! Thanks.

Comment: "*P implies Q **means** only that it is not the case that both P is true and Q is false.*" For the record, no, this is not what it means. What is universally accepted is that **if** P Implies Q, **then**, yes, *it is not the case that both P is true and Q is false*. So, "P Implies Q" **implies** "It is not the case that both P is true and Q is false". This is all we can say, so it is fallacious to claim that "P Implies Q" **means** that it is not the case that both P is true and Q is false. This is a fallacious claim which is recurrent in mathematical logic.

Comment: Note that if both P and Q are false, then it is not the case that both P is true and Q is false. If you are familiar with the basic methods of proof (e,g,  direct proof, proof by contradiction, eliminating double negation), see my blog posting on this topic. There, I formally derive each line of the truth table (among other things) from "first principles." https://dcproof.wordpress.com/2017/12/28/if-pigs-could-fly/

Answer (score 0):

An argument is considered *valid* if the conclusion cannot be false when all of the premises are true.

A hypothetical syllogism *is* a valid argument.   If *both* the premises are true, then the conclusion must be.

> The premises, B if A, and C if B, **logically entails** the conclusion that C if A.

Of course, there is *no* guarantee what the conclusion will be should any of the premises be unjustified.

If you cannot justify the premises, then a valid argument will have an unsound conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

First thanks everyone for commenting and answering in this post. You all helped me come up with my answer. After a lot "headaches" about how I should interpret them in everyday usage I understood that trying to apply logic in natural language is very difficult and sometimes isn't even usefull.

**Example**

If John is in his bedroom, Marie is in her bedroom.

Using truth tables we can evaluate the truth value of this statement. Some problems I recognize in this statement that are actually fallacies/misuse of the natural language.

1. At different times the truth values of antecedent and consequent may change. But usually we evaluated it at the moment we make the statement.
2. Someone could prove that this is a true statement based on his assumptions and use that reasoning to infer something. Suppose a friend of John who has observed that every time John goes to his bedroom, Marie goes too. He then make the assumption that this can't be change so knowing that John is in his bedroom suffices for him to conclude that Marie is in her bedroom. If someone asks him "how do you know that there is not case that antecedent is true and consequent is false" he would state the above assumptions.
3. The above statement may be also interpreted it as a promise. Two friends bet if the above statement is true or false. The winner take some amount of money. In that case they just bet and they don't try to infer anything.

Actually many of us use both 2 and 3. It is just in our nature to make assumptions and trying to conclude something. But how one should interpret them? Well someone who would like to infer something he can make assumptions and conclude that the above statement is always true that is consequent will never be false if the antecedent is true. "It can't be the case". If someone doesn't care he can view it as a bet. At the end of the day is just a matter of the truth values that make the conditional (antecednt and consequent). Antecedent will be true or false and the same for consequent. Only one of the four possible combinations will happen. Trying to guess which one of the four will happen shouldn't bother us.

Unlike natural language in mathematics implications work very well. A statement like "If P then Q" would be true or false. In such system you can actually prove because the system you work with is very strict. You have axioms and definitions. You use all that "keys" (axioms, definitions, proven theorems)  you have to a unlock (prove) a new door (theorem).  The assumptions (axioms) are stated explicitly. So what you write or what you say or how you should interpret a statement is very clear.

Comment: Your "bedroom" example would seem to be about multiple instances over a period of time, e.g. at any time over the past year, it was not the case that that John was in his bedroom and Marie was not there before he left. So, there may be instances when John is in this bedroom and Marie is not there. A logical analysis of these facts would require more than just propositional logic, which, as I understand it, deals with the state of a system at a single instant in time, usually the present.